# Adding a Label to my Storyboard in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using the latest Xcode and I am developing an iOS 10 app. Now I want to add a Button and a Label to my Storyboard. How?

I currently have the First and Second Tab/Page and im a total Xcode newbie. I had a Hackintosh but it was slow, so I bought a Mac and now I am ashamed not to know how to add a Label item. I hope they will add a VisualStudio-like Interface as a optional setting... So back to the Question, how should I add Items? I am running El Capitan if it helps.

Comment: That what their XCode shows isnt there on mine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within Xcode make sure Utilities are visible. Look at the top right of your Xcode window and ensure the Utilities icon is blue:

[image]

Now at the bottom of the Utilities pane, you should see a Filter field. In this field you can search for "Label" and "Button". When you have what you want, click and drag it to your storyboard.

I would strongly recommend you do an online Xcode course or check out some YouTube videos. It will be definitely worth the time and money!

Comment: @hungrybeast Glad it helped! To accept an answer anywhere on Stack Exchange, you will see to the left of an answer the up vote arrow and down vote arrow. Below the down vote arrow is a tick. You accept the answer by clicking the tick. Many users also click the up vote arrow as well when accepting an answer, because an up vote means the answer was useful. However, you can also click on an up vote without accepting it as the answer, and you can also click on the down vote to indicate the answer wasn't useful. If you haven't already, you should do the [tour](http://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 30):

In xcode 10.1 the Library to get a label is now on top next to the standard editor and assistant editor. I am new to xcode and was following an old video tutorial so it took me a while to find it.

[image: location of label for library xcode]

Comment: Thank you for this! I used xCode years ago and couldn't figure out why the Library of elements wasn't showing.

Comment: This must be that legendary user experience I've heard so much about 

Comment: Ditto, OJ7!  Me too.

Answer (score 21):

In Xcode 11.2, the Library's icon changed to a plus sign.
[image]

Comment: holy jezuz finally.